# Most Logic App connectors don't work within the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

I'm using the Azure Portal and want to [manually create a connector](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.ApiConnection) so that the connector fits within our naming standards.  Using the LogicApp Designer results in a name that will either conflict or be confusing if we have more than one.

As I attempt to manually create a connector, I get the following BSOD equivalent in Azure Portal.

[image]

Below is a list of problem connectors.  Notably this problem affects so many connectors, I stopped trying to track them all.

**Doesn't work**

```
app figures
asana
basecamp3
bitly
blogger
box
buffer
campfire
chatter
disqus
docusign
dropbox
Dynamics 365 for operations
dynamics 365
facebook
GitHub
Google Calendar
Google Contacts 
Google Drive
Google Sheets
GotoMeeting
GotoTraining
Harvest
```

I've tested different computers, different OS's, etc.

Comment: Looks like this is related to selection of a new resource group on the create blade. If you select an existing resource group, it should work fine. Sorry about this, have raised the issue with the product team.

Answer (score 1):

We actually meant to disable create experience for API connection from outside of the Logic Apps designer while we work on some of the edge cases. Looks like we removed the "+" from API connection blade but forget to remove it from the resource creation experience. We will go ahead and disable this for now, but know we do plan to bring it back and we understand it's not optimal to not be able to name connection exactly the way you want.

In the meantime, I believe you can use ARM deployment template to create API connections with the exact name you want.